# Find a specific word in a docx file

Tags: python, enumeration, python-docx

I am working on a group assignment to read a docx file and then output the word 'carrier' or 'carriers' with the word directly to the right of it. The output we are receiving is only 26 of the total 82 mentions of the word carrier in the document. I would prefer recommendations to what might be causing this. My hunch is that it has something to do with the For loop.

```
from docx import Document

emptyString = {}
tupl = ()
doc = Document('Interstate Commerce Act.docx')

for i ,paragraph in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
text = paragraph.text
text = text.split()
#text = text.lower()

    if 'carrier' in text:
        next = text.index('carrier') + 1
        now = text.index('carrier')
        #print(text[now], text[next]) 
        tupl = (text[now], text[next])
        emptyString[i] = tupl

    if 'carriers' in text:
        next = text.index('carriers') + 1
        now = text.index('carriers')
        #print(text[now], text[next])
        tupl = (text[now], text[next])
        emptyString[i] = tupl

    if 'Carriers' in text:
        next = text.index('Carriers') + 1
        now = text.index('Carriers')
        #print(text[now], text[next])
        tupl = (text[now], text[next])
        emptyString[i] = tupl

    if 'Carrier' in text:
        next = text.index('Carrier') + 1
        now = text.index('Carrier')
        #print(text[now], text[next])
        tupl = (text[now], text[next])   
        emptyString[i] = tupl

print(emptyString)
```

Comment: Please supply a test document that reproduces the problem. Alternatively, please describe which instances are not found. What seems to set them apart?

Comment: Do you have punctuation in your text?

Comment: Yes there is punctuation in our text. One moment on the document.

Comment: Ok here is the output, it would normally not be spaced out like this, I just wanted to show which instances were being outputted easily. https://imgur.com/a/hVvAfbG

Comment: here is a copy of the text in the docx,  https://www.ourdocuments.gov/doc.php?flash=false&doc=49&page=transcript

Answer (score 0):

Your `text = text.split()` line is going to cause certain items to be "hidden". For example, "The carrier is a Carrier." will produce the word list:

```
["The", "carrier", "is", "a", "Carrier."]
```

Since the last item is "Carrier." and not "Carrier" it will not be found by your "exact match" test.

Perhaps better to split by word and then check whether a *lowercase* version *includes* "carrier":

```
words = text.split()
for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if "carrier" in word.lower():
        print("word %d is a match" % i)
```

Using the lowercase comparison avoids the need for separate tests for all the case varieties.